# Is there any wifi-enabled shockproof (i.e rugged) digital camera?

Tags: camera-recommendation, file-transfer

Suppose I need to take photos everyday and upload them to a PC wirelessly. I don't want to use an extra eyefi sd card for that. Is there a camera which will do this?

Comment: Why do you not want to use an 'eyefi' add in card? This gives you maximum flexibility in camera choice as the majority of cameras do not have integral WiFi and you are very greatly limiting your choice this way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using an 'eyefi' add in card would give you maximum flexibility in camera choice as the majority of cameras do not have integral WiFi and you are very greatly limiting your choice this way.

HOWEVER

Depending on application, **an excellent sounding candidate** is [Ricoh's G700SE](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/digitalcameras/ricoh-announces-rugged-g700se-camera-with-bluetooth-wifi-plus-gps-and-barcode-options/4048)

[Ricoh G700SE home page](http://www.ricoh.com/r_dc/g/g700se/)

[Specifications](http://www.ricoh.com/r_dc/g/g700se/specs.html)

[Features page](http://www.ricoh.com/r_dc/g/g700se/features.html) including -

- Despite its small size and light weight, the G700SE has strengthened glass at the lens front surface and body protectors added at strategic points. This toughness enabled it to withstand 2.0 m drops in 26 positions (6 surfaces, 8 corners, and 12 edges) in testing conforming to US Department of Defense “MIL Standard 810F.” Furthermore, it also passes this test with the power on.
- Bluetooth & WiFi, plus GPS and barcode options.
- Introduced in late 2010. 12 megapixel,
- Shockproof, dustproof, and waterproof to about 16 feet and chemical resistant for industrial usage.
- 28 -140mm (f/3.5-5.5) 5x optical zoom lens and a 3-inch, 920,000-dot LCD
- Built-in WiFi and Bluetooth support, and optional GPS and laser barcode reader accessories.
- Features support for SD-WORM memory cards, which offer password-protected, tamper-proof image recording capabilities (aimed at law-enforcement or other high-security uses).

[image]

---

[Samsung - January 2012](http://mashable.com/2012/01/09/samsung-wifi-cameras-ces2012/)

3 WiFi equipped models. No claims to ruggedness per se - wjhat that means to you and whether it can be added wih an external case is TBD.

- WB850F ($379), WB150F ($229) and ST200F ($199) all have Wi-Fi, letting photographers send images straight from the camera to friends via email or upload them to a service like Flickr or YouTube.
- WB850F: 21X optical zoom, 16-megapixel, 1080p video.
  Can run at hundreds of frames per second to recreate scenes in slow motion.
  Internal GPS. 3-inch AMOLED rear screen.
- The WB150F: 14MP, 18X optical zoom and 1080p video recording.
- ST200F 720p recording, 10X optical zoom.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of any, but you can get an EyeFi card for any rugged camera that takes SD.
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=eyefi

Answer (score 1):

Another option is the JVC Addixxion, which was launched at the end of June.  it's significantly waterproof, shockproof and will even broadcast live, via its inbuild wifi and a mobile hotspot to Ustream ! http://www.jvc.co.uk/article.php?id=100552

Comment: nice to pin up here, though I meant still camera initially :)

Comment: Can the Addixxion take photos as requested in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Samsung just annouced a camera with WiFi and cell-phone data. Not sure how rugged it is, but its designed exactly to be used all the time, every day, and feed social networks.

http://www.dpreview.com/news/2012/08/29/Samsung-Galaxy-Camera